# Biphenyl esterification

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds

[image: 6,6'-bis(hydroxymethyl)[1,1'-biphenyl]-2,2'-dicarboxylic acid]

I was wondering that at optimum temperature can 6,6'-bis(hydroxymethyl)[1,1'-biphenyl]-2,2'-dicarboxylic acid show esterification reaction.

I know that the two phenyl groups aren't in the same plane so is esterification reaction still possible?

Comment: What conditions do you intend to use for the esterification? Acid catalysed or with a coupling agent?

Comment: There's a base present ie NaOH and the temperature is of 100°C

Comment: You are not going to get esterification with NaOH present!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

these type of things are possible,

[image]

---

[image]

esterification is possible, check the reference.

Comment: Can the carboxylic acid and alcohol react to give an ester at 100°C of temperature??

Comment: is this for research purpose ? or just exercise?

Comment: It's for my knowledge and a part of my excercise